# How can I keep placards dry when demonstrating in the rain?

Tags: paper, weather, demonstration

I'm planning to attend some demonstration these coming days. However, winter is upon us, and there's going to be rain. And the placards are made of paper; thick paper board, but still paper, which will not withstand anything more than a light drizzle.

Now, you must be thinking: "Use a large umbrella". But the thing is, I need both hands to hold my placard. (Plus, an umbrella is rather unwieldy, and makes you a more attractive target to opponents of the demonstration.)

So, what would you recommend as a solution for keeping my demonstration placards(s) dry and visible?

Notes:

- If you suggest using a different material, note that poster longevity is generally low because the police often tears them up or confiscates them. Also, assume there is currently a set of posters that I need to work with and they're paper.
- The location is Israel/Palestine, and the temperature is low, but markedly above zero.

Answer (score 3):

You could wear rain gear to protect yourself and warm clothes underneath.

For the poster board you can try a clear acrylic spray paint or even get large sheets of thermal laminate to cover your poster board.

With the laminate you can use a simple household iron to seal it and it would be waterproof with the added benefit of being much harder to tear and destroy.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of spray paint you mean? And how that protects the paper? Anyway, lamination is an interesting idea; although I wonder how much time that would take for each poster.

Comment: @einpoklum Any clear polyurethane or acrylic cans of spray paint. Not sure what brands you have available in your location which is why I didn't name any specifically.  I would go to a local home improvement or hardware store and grab a can, bring it home, make up a sample poster and try it out in the shower. I am not sure how posters you have but laminating would probably go fairly quick.

Comment: You could also try a corrugated plastic for your poster boards and then a clear poly or acrylic over top, that would work great too!

Comment: More difficult to sketch posters on corrugated plastic, plus it's much more expensive, but I suppose I'll have to consider it.

Comment: @einpoklum, matt: spray paint in the shower? Apart from speckling the walls with paint, it would be hard avoid breathing the rebound. No reason to do even a quick test inside.

Comment: Reading comprehension goes a long way. I didn't say go spray the paint in the shower. Paint the poster and put it in the shower to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

- Cover the placard with [**cling film**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_wrap), wrapped round to the back.
- If the film isn't wide enough, use more strips *vertically* to make it rain proof.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for keeping yourself dry:-
I have one of these...

[image: Umbrella hat]

to keep my head dry and both my hands free.  They are very effective and very cheap.